# Excel VBA - Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, worksheet

I have two worksheets (sheet1 and sheet2). Both contain a column with header "ID" (columns are not always in the same position so need to be found).

Needed is a vlookup in a new column before the "ID" column.

This is what I got so far

```
sub vlookup ()

    FIND COLUMNS WITH "ID"-HEADER

        'Set variables for Column Sku
        'note: cfind1 is for sheet 1 and cfind 2 is for sheet 2

            Dim col As String, cfind1 As Range, cfind2 As Range

            column = "ID"

            Worksheets(1).Activate
            Set cfind1 = Cells.Find(what:=column, lookat:=xlWhole)

            Worksheets(2).Activate
            Set cfind2 = Cells.Find(what:=column, lookat:=xlWhole)


    'CREATE COLUMN WITH VLOOKUP

            'activate worksheet 1
            Worksheets(1).Activate

            'add column before sku-column
            cfind1.EntireColumn.Insert

            'Select cell 1 down and 1 to left of sku-cell.
            cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Select

            'Add VlookUp formulas in active cell
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(LookUpValue, TableArray,1,0)"

                '(Lookup_Value should refer to one cell to the right 
                 (= cfind1.Offset (1, 0)??)

                'Table_Array should refer to the column in sheet(2) with header "id"


             'Autofill Formula in entire column
                 '???
End Sub
```

Everything is working fine until the "vlookup-part"
I managed to put a formula in the correct cell, but I just can't get the formula to work.

**How can I set lookup_value as "one cell to the right" in the same sheet 
and "table_array" as the column with header "ID" in worksheet(2)?**

**And how can I finally autofill the vlookup formula throughout the whole column?**

It would be great if anybody can help me out with the correct vlookup formula / variables and the autofilling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use something similar to below should you want to avoid using the worksheet

```
curr_stn = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(curr_ref, Sheets("Word_Specifications").Range("N:O"), 2, False)
```

Valuse/variables will need to be changed of course. lookup_value,Array (range), Column number, Exact match.

Exact match needs false and similar match needs true

Try below full code

```
Sub t()

Dim col As String, cfind1 As Range, cfind2 As Range

            Column = "ID"

            Worksheets(1).Activate
            Set cfind1 = Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole)

            Worksheets(2).Activate
            Set cfind2 = Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole)


    'CREATE COLUMN WITH VLOOKUP

            'activate worksheet 1
            Worksheets(1).Activate

            'add column before sku-column
            cfind1.EntireColumn.Insert

            'Select cell 1 down and 1 to left of sku-cell.
            cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Select

            'Add VlookUp formulas in active cell
            LookUp_Value = cfind1.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False)
            Table_Array = Col_Letter(Worksheets(2).Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole).Column) & ":" & Col_Letter(Worksheets(2).Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole).Column)
            ws_name = Worksheets(2).Name
            Col_index_num = 1
            Range_Lookup = False
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & LookUp_Value & ", " & ws_name & "!" & Table_Array & ", " & Col_index_num & ", " & Range_Lookup & ")"

            'Autofill Formula in entire column
            lastrow = Range(cfind1.Address).End(xlDown).Row
            Range(cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range(cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Address & ":" & Col_Letter(cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Column) & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault


End Sub


Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It's actually the variables and how I integrate them into the vlookup formula that I am actually looking for. How can I set lookup_value as "one cell to the right" in the same sheet and  "table_array" as the column with header "ID" in worksheet(2)?

Comment: just posted a full code example. see how it all works together? just a side note but the macro recorder is your friend :)

Comment: Thanks very much again. Unfortunately the macro recorder was of no use for this. This because column "ID" is not always in the same position. Sometimes it will be located in column G, sometimes column E etc.

I have tried your code. Very impressive, hard for me too understand everything you did as I'm not that much of an expert. It returns a run time error 13, type mismatch in " `code` Table_Array = Col_Letter(Worksheets(2).Cells.Find(what:=column, lookat:=xlWhole).column) & ":" & Col_Letter(Worksheets(2).Cells.Find(what:=column, lookat:=xlWhole).column) `code`

Comment: AH! my bad, missed the function. I have included the function Col_Letter in the above which needs to be included(may have to scroll down in above to see it). The macro recorder is normally a good starting point and then to adjust as needed so to speak, some times it helps and sometimes it does not

Comment: Almost there.   Jeez, I am trying hard to understand all aspects of your code.   Thanks so much for all this.  
The VlookUp formula is now entered perfectly working in the correct cell.   You have no idea how happy I am to finally see it there :)

The last challenge now is to get the autofill right.   I guess it should activate/select  `cfind1.Offset(1, -1)` and autofill from there. I tried replacing "B2" in your code with cfind1.Offset(1, -1).Select, but it's not working. The formula only stays visible in one cell. Do you think it is possible as well to find a solution for this?

Comment: I have amended code above so that the ranges for autofill is now coming from cfind1. That should autofill as expected now.

Comment: Selecting cells and doing things with the sheet can be very costly in terms of CPU time, it should be avoided if possible. for example this Worksheets(1).Activate
            Set cfind1 = Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole) --- Could become Set cfind1 = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(what:=Column, lookat:=xlWhole) --- hence removing the need to activate the sheet

Comment: Thank you so so much. I am extremely happy. It is working perfectly now. As well thanks for your advice regarding cpu-load. I didn't think about that. You absolutely were of great help. Thanks again!  Regards Sid

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this before but my approach would be to use the cell or range.formula property and build the string that you would write in the cell. for example:

`myrange.formula = "=Vlookup("&Lookup_Value&","&Table_Array&","&Col_index_num&","&Range_Lookup&")"`

Comment: Hi Danny. Thanks so much for your response.
Your option may contain part of the solution. I have tried it but still don't manage to get it working. What i get is "Compile error, syntax error"

I have already been able to add a formula in the correct cell with:

ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(LookUpValue, TableArray,1,0)"

However I do not know how to refer to the correct lookupvalue and table arry within this vlookup.